# Understanding proof of Evan's PDE, THEOREM $1$ ( Solving Poisson's equation )

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading the Evan's PDE, theorem 1 ( p.23 ) and some questions arise. I found assoicated question but I think that I don't get satisfactory answer yet.

Now assume $f\in C^{2}_C(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

> Theorem 1. ( Solving Poisson's euqation ) Define $u$ by $(8)$ ;
> $$ u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy = \begin{cases}
> \frac{-1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \log(|x-y|)f(y)dy  & (n=2) \\
> \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}dy & (n \ge 3)
> \end{cases}$$. Then (i) $u\in C^2( \mathbb{R}^n)$ and (ii) $-
> \Delta u = f $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

In the proof of the (ii), he argues as follows :

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Then

$$\Delta u(x)= \int_{B(0, \epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0, \epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy =: I_{\epsilon} + J_{\epsilon}$$

Now,  $$|I_{\epsilon}|\le C ||D^2 f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}|\Phi(y)|dy \le \begin{cases}
C\epsilon^2|\log \epsilon|  & (n=2) \\
C\epsilon^2 & (n \ge 3)
\end{cases}$$

. **My first question is**, why the first inequality is true? ; i.e., why $|\Delta_x f(x-y)| \le C ||D^2f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is true? By the definition of $L^{\infty}$-norm?

**EDIT** : This is answered by [A question about the proof of theorem 1 section 2.2.1 of the evans pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594384/a-question-about-the-proof-of-theorem-1-section-2-2-1-of-the-evans-pde/3619062#3619062) .

And he continue to argue as follows. An integration by parts ( $\because$ Green's formula, see C.2. ) yields

$$ J_{\epsilon} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_y f(x-y)dy \\
 = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0, \epsilon)} D\Phi(y) \cdot D_y f (x-y) dy + \int_{\partial B(0, \epsilon)}\Phi(y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}(x-y)dS(y) =: K_{\epsilon} + L_{\epsilon}$$

$\nu$ denoting theh inward pointing unit normal along $\partial B(0, \epsilon)$. ( Next proof is omitted..)

**My second question is**, why the first equality for $J_\epsilon$ is true? ; i.e., why

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0, \epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_xf(x-y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)\Delta_y f(x-y)dy$$ ? Is it o.k. to change $x$ in $\Delta_x$ to $y$ in subsequent argument ( although I did not upload full proof until now )?

**And third, finally, I raise question for making certainly sure.** In the book p.25 he reachs to conclusion that for arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$K_\epsilon(x) = -\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}f(y)dS(y) \to -f(x) $$

as $\epsilon \to 0$ ( Note that $n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}$ is the surface area of the sphere $\partial B(0,\epsilon)$. ) I tried to show this convergence as follows.

Fix $\eta>0$. Since $f\in C^{2}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|y-x| < \delta$, then $|f(y)-f(x)| < \eta$. We now show that

$$ \rvert \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}f(y)dS(y) -f(x) \lvert < \eta $$

for all $0 < |\epsilon|=\epsilon < \delta$, which is our goal. First, for $y\in \partial B(x,\epsilon)$, we have $|y-x|=\epsilon < \delta$. So,

$$ \rvert \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}f(y)dS(y) -f(x) \lvert \\= \rvert \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}f(y)dS(y) -f(x) \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}dS(y) \lvert 
 \\= \rvert \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y) -f(x) dS(y) \lvert \\ \le \frac{1}{n \alpha(n) \epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}|f(y)-f(x)| dS(y) < \eta \cdot \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)\epsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}dS(y) = \eta. $$

So we are done. Correct?

Comment: I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783012/doubt-about-a-passage-on-page-24-of-the-evans-partial-differential-equations-boo/4057264#4057264 answers your first question

Comment: O.K. Thank you. Your linked post is relavant to my first question. And I comment a my own further question for your answer in the linked post.

Comment: Laplacian is like two derivatives, so when you use some sort of chain rule/change of variables, the minuses coming from the $-y$ in $f(x-y)$ cancels out. Your last computation seems to check out for me, note that this is just some kind of mean value type theorem for integrals.

Comment: @FinnPillar : Thank you. And.. you seem to have hinted for certain rationality but I don't understand your natural language statement. Perhaps, could you please explain more formally with an example?.. I think that now I'm not good at calculation accompanying chain rule/ change of variables.

Comment: Since the laplacian is just the sum of the second partials, I will just write this, $\partial_{y_i} f(x-y)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)$, do the same again to get $\partial^2_{y_i y_i} f(x-y)=+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}(x-y)$.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851972/a-laplacian-identity-from-evans?rq=1 may answer your question more clearly.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask more for rigor? I am in trouble for extension of the answer in your linked post to higher dimension. Why $\partial_{y_i}f(x-y) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x-y)$? A priori, similar to the answer ( $n=1$ case ) in the linked post, it seems works and I am trying to show it by direct calculation. And in the first comment of yours, you wrote that "this is just some kind of mean value type theorem for integrals." What did you mean by that sentence? ( Your sentence seems to imply that there are several similar types of theorems. )  Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: That is just by the (multivariable) chain rule, maybe you would want to revisit vector calculus for a precise statement. Anyhow, the mean value type theorem statement doesn't really mean anything, just that is is somehow similar to the classical mean value theorem for integrals for real functions. To be precise, every point of a continuous function is a Lebesgue point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point can be shown by the mean value theorem.

Comment: O.K. Thanks :) I will refer~

Comment: Also, indeed there are several type of these mean value theorems, maybe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695170/mean-value-theorem-for-multivariate-integral/4874421#4874421 would be interesting to you.

Comment: Uhm.. Yes, O.K. : ) Thank you.